# Convert list of ints to sql binary(8) list

Tags: c#, .net, linq, ado.net, type-conversion

I have a simple application that has richTextBox and button.
User enters numbers(integers) into richTextBox (one number per line).

When He click the button I want to generate a sql query.

Basically it works if I pass integers into query like this:

```
SELECT price from products where ID IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

This is when user inputs 1,2,3,4 as lines in richTextBox.

But I would like pass binary(8) instead of integers.

This is my original line of code:

```
cmdString += " IN (" + string.Join(", ", richTextBox1.Lines) + ") ";
```

I have tried to change it with LINQ like this:

```
cmdString += " IN ("
+ string.Join(", ", richTextBox1.Lines.Select(c => 
    { c = "0x"+Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(c), 16); 
     return c; 
    }).ToArray())
+ ") ";
```

What I would like to get:

For example convert:

```
 1   to  0x0000000000000001
30   to  0x000000000000001E
```

I hope You get the point.

**Update:**

I've done this:

```
textBox1.Text = string.Join(", ", richTextBox1.Lines.Select(c =>
    {
        c = "0x" + "0000000000000000".Substring(0, (16 - Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(c), 16).Length)) + Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(c), 16);
        return c;
    }).ToArray());
```

Any ideas how to remove second `Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(c))` usage? Or maybe do it in another way?

Comment: the "original line of code" is also ripe for SQL injection

Comment: If I do a simple select in MS SQL Server 2005 with leading 0s I get my result, but without them nothing :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll do this in foreach loop:

```
var query = "Select ... In( ";

foreach(var item in Lines)
{
   int a = 0;
   if (!int.TryParse(item, out a))
     throw new IllegalInputException();
   query += "0x" + Convert.ToString(a, 16).PadLeft(16, '0');
}
...
```

Or you can do it in your linq query but not easy to read as foreach one:

```
cmdString += " IN (" 
+ string.Join(", ", richTextBox1.Lines.Select(c => 
    { c = "0x"+Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(c), 16)
               .PadLeft(16, '0'); 
     return c; 
    }).ToArray())  

+ ") ";
```

Comment: This works just like mine solution, but it uses PadLeft. Never used that before. Thanks :)

Comment: There is one little mistake. In PadLeft first argument must be 16 not 16-length. First argument is total length of our result string.

Comment: all the thanks must go to You :) You've solved my problem and I've learned how to use PadLeft. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
var binaryStrings = richTextBox1.Lines
                    .Select(str => String.Format("'0x{0}'", 
                                   Convert.ToString(int.Parse(str), 16)));
var cmd = String.Format("SELECT price from products where ID IN ({0})", 
                                   String.Join(",", binaryStrings));
```

[Convert.ToString Method (Int32, Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14kwkz77.aspx)

Comment: It must be 16 instead of 8 :) The second thing is that I need those leading 0s, without them my select don't work. I don't know why :/

Comment: @Misiu: I don't understand. The leading zeros are added in `String.Format("'0x{0}'"`. Note that i've added apostrophes, i don't think that it works in SQL-Server otherwise. Remove them if i'm wrong. Changed the base from 8 to 16.

Comment: I have tried doing a simple select. If I do like this: 'select * from products where ID=0x0000000000000001' I get my result, if I remove leading zeros I don't get any records. Mayby it is something with my sql server configuration